# Locating serial port

Tags: serial, uart

I'm not sure if this is the correct stack exchange site to post this, but here goes.

I have this PCB:

[image: photo]

It's from this: https://www.vasco.com/images/DP270_Xpress_april11_tcm42-47389.pdf

I'm trying to locate a serial, uart port, if one exists. I don't have an oscilloscope or a multimeter, although I could possibly buy a multimeter if needs be. Any help?

Comment: You're not going to be able to get anything useful from that.

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: It looks like it has an ISP connection (the rectangular outline with 6 pads inside called J1 - as it has a pad called RST) but beyond that who knows.

Comment: @Tom ISP connection? Mind expanding on that?

Comment: ISP or In-circuit serial Programming ports are found on lots of microcontroller based products and are how the chips get programmed (UART etc.). They usually have 6 pins with one of them being the reset, I was only taking a guess as there was a bank of what looked like 6 pins surrounded by a silkscreen rectangle with a label that said "RST" near by. It's possible that it could instead be some JTAG port or some arbitrary manufacturer specific port, I was hazarding a guess as at least it's a possibility and is something to try. It's going to be hard without a scope or some programming adapters.

Comment: @tom you think it's possible with a multimeter? I'm thinking it might destroy the circuit.

Comment: A multimeter is unlikley to cause any problems if on the volts range as it's input resistance is high enough (10Mohms) that it's like it isn't there, although a multimeter is unlikely to tell you anything more than what voltage is on a pin (the ohms and current ranges won't really help you work out which pins are data either). It'd be best to get a few of these things and try hooking them up to some programming headers, unless you feed 12v into the pins or something, you probably won't hurt the circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to locate a serial, uart port, if one exists.

Since your PCB is from a [handheld OTP (one time password) generator](https://www.vasco.com/products/two-factor-authenticators/hardware/e-signature/pin-protected/digipass-270.html) and *should* be designed to be secure, the chances of you finding a serial port on that PCB should be minimal.

> I don't have an oscilloscope or a multimeter, although I could possibly buy a multimeter if needs be.

Without any test equipment, your chance of finding an unlabelled serial port even if it exists, is near zero. :-(  However even a multimeter would be useless, since it would not allow you to determine whether a signal is a UART-format serial signal, or some other data signal.

Sensible tools which would allow you to investigate further, would include an oscilloscope or a logic analyser (and the knowledge of how to use them). However even then, as I said above, I believe that your chances of finding a serial port are minimal (effectively zero) due to the origins of that PCB, especially as you are a beginner in reverse engineering.

Note that many designs don't include a serial port, so don't assume that there will be one on every PCB you find!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was sceptical about whether I was going to get one. I guess I should maybe look at other ways to reverse engineer it. Any tips?

Comment: You're welcome - here we say thanks by [voting](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) :-) You want other ways to reverse engineer something which *should* be designed for that to be difficult, without test equipment? Sorry, I think you're wasting your time :-( If you edit your question & add at the bottom more information about what *exactly* you want to achieve (e.g. is this just for fun; does it matter if you damage that PCB; what result do you expect e.g. are you trying to get the internal PIN number, or something else; etc. etc.) then you *might* get more suggestions.

Comment: To understand more about these devices, you may find these pages from Wikipedia to be interesting: [Security token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token) and [One-time password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password). The small "watch crystal", just below the test pads, top-right of the PCB, shows that this device is likely to be a time-synchronised OTP generator, such that the OTP will change depending on when it is generated.

Comment: I tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation. :P It's just for fun. I legit want to do anything with it that I can, to get any kind of information. It's just for learning purposes really, and it was the coolest bit of spare tech I had lying around.